# ndb.key() -> do this with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In my applicatoin I get keys that are constructed in a Python system, writing to Google Datastore.

To match the data, I need the ID's of these items, and they are in the 'key' string.

I cannot do key.id() since I do not have Python, I need to 'decode' it manually using JavaScript / Google Apps Script.

Is this possible?

```
key = Key(urlsafe=url_string)
kind_string = key.kind()
ident = key.id()
```

Comment: How are you getting the key into your javascript in the first place?

Comment: I fetch it with REST from the Google Datastore. It is saved there as a JSON-blob object, that I decode and parse. This object contains the key strings as a reference but I cannot use those directly.

Comment: But the [datastore JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/key) should give you the decoded key already.

Comment: Not really, not in this case. What I actually get from the datastore is a stringified, binairy version of this.  I have no control about what is saved in there because it is a different application storing this, I can only read data. (When I base64 decode that key, I can recognize the entity, but the ID has strange characters)

[
  {
    "not_applicable": false,
    "key": "aghlfmFoLXdibxxxxxxxxxxxVlc3Rpb24YgICAgPjChAoM",
    "given_score": 0
  },
  {
    "not_applicable": true,
    "key": "aghlfmFoLXdibxxxxxxxxxxxxlc3Rpb24YgICAgIDkkQoM",
    "given_score": 0
  },

etc

Comment: I actually get this when I decode:

"je~pb-wbmrQuestion༡≌䀀"

I know e~pb-wbm and Question (the path and the entity)

Comment: Well, that decoded string is actually a serialized representation of the Protocol Buffer class that defines the key (Google uses protobufs internally for almost everything). You won't easily be able to extract the data using JS, without finding a whole load of third-party libraries. Better to get the application that's providing this data to send it in a more easily decoded form.

Comment: It is always good to know when to stop trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  Longer answer, not without a lot of work.
@danielroseman explains it well in his comments.

Normally, keys should stay on the server since they are only useful to ndb.  You can pass around the `id = key.id()` value for constructing a new key with `new_key = ndb.Key(Model, id)`.

If you must pass the key around, use `safe_key = key.urlsafe()` and reconstruct it using `ndb.Key(urlsafe=safe_key)`.